# Displacement distortion

Tags: displacement, vector

By some reason displacement became directed and to perpendicular to normals. Tried to kill user preferences and check it in new scene - same thing: it's always distorted. 
[image]

Please, HALP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting. Iv'e used stable 2.79 and looks like back then it automatically added Displacement node between shader input and map output, and 2.79+ doesn't do that. After adding it manually everything started to work how it supposed to. Even with old preferences. Yay!

[image]

Comment: You’ll notice that the Displacement socket is *blue* to indicate it’s a vector rather than a scalar (grey). This means that the displacement no longer occurs in the direction of the normal but is determined by the vector. Your black and white are effectively the vectors (0,0,0) and (1,1,1) and this is skewing the displacement. The new Displacement node takes the input and generates the correct vector for displacement along the normal.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thanks for the explanation!